# Two parallel but different datasets in Keras as multiple inputs?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have been googling all day trying to find an example of the functional input for two parallel datasets in Keras but I can't find one.

My problem is that I have dataset 1, a set of images of people performing different actions. It is formatted as a csv as follows:

```
image_url,class
example1.png,BRUSH_TEETH
example2,BRUSH_TEETH
...
example10000.png,DANCING
```

I will preprocess these and make them all 64x64 in size. My second dataset will be leap motion data where every row is information captured at the same time as the corresponding row in dataset 1

(ignore the column names and values, I'm not sure how they will look like yet as I haven't gathered the data, but they will be one row and parallel to the above dataset1)

```
x,y,z,a,b,c,d,class
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,BRUSH_TEETH
8,9,10,3,1,3,4,BRUSH_TEETH
...
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,DANCING
```

I have been reading about the functional API and it seems as if I can run the data object from dataset1 through a CNN while running the same data object from dataset2 through, for example, a deep MLP. Then, using merge or concatenate, bring the two outputs from their final layers to another deep MLP and then finally link this final merged model to an output

Forgetting about the CNN for a minute, a simple example of merging is given by the API as follows:

```
import keras

input1 = keras.layers.Input(shape=(16,))
x1 = keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu')(input1)
input2 = keras.layers.Input(shape=(32,))
x2 = keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu')(input2)
# equivalent to added = keras.layers.add([x1, x2])
added = keras.layers.Add()([x1, x2])

out = keras.layers.Dense(4)(added)
model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[input1, input2], outputs=out)
```

My problem is that I need to feed input1 (when in the form of a CNN) the image contained in the csv while at the same time feeding input2 with the correlating row in the second dataset containing Leap Motion data. PS: how in the above would I continue the model after merging with two dense layers before output? Would it be simply this:

```
x3 = keras.layers.Dense(100)(added)
x3 = keras.layers.Dense(50)(x3)
out = keras.layers.Dense(4)(x3)
```

Is this possible to perform? If so, I would MASSIVELY appreciate a helping hand, I'm losing my mind trying to get my head around how the two datasets would be kept in sync with one another!

A sample script that I can try out and play with would be excellent, as I'm relatively new to the Keras framework

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you read this? https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro thank you for the suggestion, I have read it but I can't quite see where or how the mixed data from multiple datasets are kept in sync as inputs

Comment: Each input array has to match 1:1 in terms of indices, that is what you would call sync.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please check if this is useful. Tested with Keras 2.2.4.

```
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Input, Dense, Flatten, concatenate
from keras.models import Model
import numpy as np

img_input = Input(shape=(64, 64, 1))  ## branch 1 with image input
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3))(img_input)
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3))(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Flatten()(x)
out_a = Dense(64)(x)

num_input = Input(shape=(7,))        ## branch 2 with numerical input
x1 = Dense(8, activation='relu')(num_input)
out_b = Dense(16, activation='relu')(x1)

concatenated = concatenate([out_a, out_b])    ## concatenate the two branches
out = Dense(4, activation='softmax')(concatenated)
model = Model([img_input, num_input], out)
print(model.summary())
model.compile('sgd', 'categorical_crossentropy', ['accuracy'])

### Just for sanity check
X = [np.zeros((1,64,64,1)), np.zeros((1,7))]
y = np.ones((1,4))
model.fit(X, y)
print(model.predict(X))
```

You can read the input data using Pandas

```
from PIL import Image
import pandas as pd

def get_num_input():
    df = pd.read_csv('num.csv')
    columns = list(df.columns)
    features = columns[:-1]
    cls_name = columns[-1]
    X = np.zeros((len(df), len(features)))
    Y = list()
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        X[i] = row[features]
        Y.append(row[cls_name])

    return (X, Y)

def get_img_input():
    df = pd.read_csv('img.csv')
    X_img = np.zeros((len(df), 28, 28)) # change as per image size
    Y = list()
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        X_img[i] = np.array(Image.open(row['image_url']))
        Y.append(row['class'])

    return (X_img, Y)


X_num, Y = get_num_input()
X_img, _ = get_img_input() # use one of the Ys
# X feature normalization, convert Y to one-hot representation
```

model.fit() has a *'validation_split'* parameter which can be set to 0.3 to create a 70:30 split. model.fit() returns a History object which can be used to plot the accuracy curves or you can use TensorBoard callback for live tracking.

https://chrisalbon.com/deep_learning/keras/visualize_loss_history/
https://keras.io/callbacks/#tensorboard

Comment: Thank you very much Manoj, would you possibly be able to add the part where I would define my two csv datasets and feed them in to each branch? Also, could you explain how they are fitted/trained with their defined class in the data at a say 70/30 split into history so I can graph its progress later on?

Comment: Updated the answer based on your questions.

Comment: Genius. Thank you.